# select all from several tables where one column is matching all

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do something similar to this using php and mysql database:

```
SELECT * FROM accomodation,assessment,beneficiaries,site 
FROM accomodation,assessment,beneficiaries,site 
WHERE ITS_Code != "none"
```

`ITS_Code` is mutual between all tables.
Thank you

Comment: `accomodation,assessment,beneficiaries,site` all this your `DB` table name.

Comment: use UNION of 4 queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Join

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.* 
FROM accomodation as  a
LEFT Join assessment as b on a.ITS_Code = b.ITS_Code 
LEFT JOIN beneficiaries as c on a.ITS_Code = c.ITS_Code 
LEFT JOIN site as d on a.ITS_Code = d.ITS_Code 
WHERE a.ITS_Code != "none"
```

Comment: You have an error?   . worng result? no result?  . update your question with a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: An alias was previously found. (near "a" at position 138)

Comment: I have slightly update  the answer .. show me the exact complete error message  (update you answer  and add also the code you are using)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that tables **accomodation**, **assessment**, **beneficiaries**, and **site** has equal number of columns, and you're only looking to list each table's content consecutively, you could do:

```sql
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM accomodation
WHERE ITS_code <> "none"

UNION ALL

SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM assessment
WHERE ITS_code <> "none"

UNION ALL

SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM beneficiaries
WHERE ITS_code <> "none"

UNION ALL

SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM site
WHERE ITS_code <> "none"
```

If one of the table has unequal number of columns - say, **site** has only 2 columns - then you could `SELECT NULL` in its place, like:

```sql
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM accomodation
WHERE ITS_code <> "none"

UNION ALL

SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM assessment
WHERE ITS_code <> "none"

UNION ALL

SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM beneficiaries
WHERE ITS_code <> "none"

UNION ALL

SELECT Column1, Column2, NULL AS Column3 FROM site
WHERE ITS_code <> "none"
```